# verb + "to have" + past-participle

Tags: present-perfect, infinitives

> He needed [to have not gone](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22to%20have%20not%20gone%22&rlz=1C1GCEU_enPK819PK819&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj2rv6ktZfgAhVSRxUIHQeiAXkQ_AUIEigA&biw=1535&bih=794) there.

Above is a vague way of saying *He needed not to go there.*, and I think that would be very inappropriate too. I am more interested in knowing whether that would be any ways acceptable in formal or informal conversations? Is the sentence grammatical?

P.S. I believe there must be a difference in context too between both the sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We form the perfect infinitive with to have + the -ed form of a verb. We use the perfect infinitive after verbs such as claim, expect, hate, hope, like, love, prefer, pretend:

> He **pretended to have lost** her number and so had been unable to contact
>   her. (or He pretended that he had lost her number …)

The perfect infinitive often refers to things that might have happened in the past:

> She **claims to have met** a number of famous people, but I don’t believe
>   her. (or She claims she has met …)
>
> I would **prefer to have stayed** at a small, family-run hotel than a big
>   international chain. (I prefer to stay at small hotels, but I did
>   not.)

The perfect infinitive can refer to something that will be completed at a point in the future:

> We **hope to have finished** the building works by the end of March.

We can use the perfect infinitive in a clause with a verb that has no subject (a non-finite clause). It can refer to events which did happen in the past or to events that might have happened (but did not happen):

> **To have got the job** in the face of such stiff competition **was** a great
>   achievement. (The person did get the job.)
>
> **To have won the race** **would** have been fantastic, but even coming second
>   was a great achievement. (The person did not win the race.)

Source: [Perfect infinitive with to (to have worked)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/perfect-infinitive-with-to-to-have-worked)

Answer (score 0):

Your example sentence is a quasi-modal use of the verb **need** where it is synonymous with **ought** or **should**.  It is grammatical.

> He needed to have not gone there.
>
> He should not have gone there.

The perfect always involves a time, implicit or explicit, that serves as a reference point. The action involved is relative to that reference.   So, **to have gone there** implies a time when the going there is deemed to have taken place. In a way, the construction is retrospective, looking back over its shoulder. Here, in other words: ***In hindsight*, he should not have gone there.**